# How to Move the first two words to the two words thereafter in PHP?

Tags: php

I know this is kinda weird, *but I need this to complete my task*.

I want to move the first two words to the two words thereafter, example is in my (error) code :

```
<?
$sentence = "zero one two three four five six seven eight";
$sentence2 = explode (" ",$sentence);
$total = count($sentence2);
for ($i = 4; $i < $total; ++$i) {
$result = $sentence2[2]." ".$sentence2[3]." ".$sentence2[0]." ".$sentence2[1]."  ".$sentence2[$i];
}
echo "Original sentence : ".$sentence;
echo "<br>Result : ".$result;
?>
```

but the result from that code is not what i want, the result is

```
two three zero one eight
```

i want the result :

```
two three zero one four five six seven eight
```

can you help me make a better code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time the code inside your loop runs, the `$result` variable receives a new value.

You should only **append** words at the end of the sequence to it.

So, replace you `for` loop by this:

```
$result = $sentence2[2]." ".$sentence2[3]." ".$sentence2[0]." ".$sentence2[1];
for ($i = 4; $i < $total; ++$i) {
    $result .= "  ".$sentence2[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [array_splice](http://cn.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) for this case

```
$sentence = "zero one two three four five six seven eight";
$words    = explode(" ",$sentence,3);
$base     = explode(" ",$words[2]);
array_splice($base,2,0,array($words[0],$words[1]));
echo implode(" ",$base);
```

or one line solution,:-)

```
echo preg_replace('#^(\w+\s+)(\w+\s+)(\w+\s+)(\w+\s+)#','$3$4$1$2',$sentence);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you overwrite the result all the time.
So when it steps through your for-loop the first time the string will be

```
two three zero one five
```

The second time it will be

```
two three zero one six
```

etc.

But you will only see it ending by eight because you output the string only at the end.
You should store your new string in a variable and append your next number to that.
It should read something like;

```
<?
$sentence = "zero one two three four five six seven eight";
$sentence2 = explode (" ",$sentence);
$total = count($sentence2);
$result = $sentence2[2]." ".$sentence2[3]." ".$sentence2[0]." ".$sentence2[1]."  ";
for ($i = 4; $i < $total; ++$i) {
$result = $result."  ".$sentence2[$i];
}
echo "Original sentence : ".$sentence;
echo "<br>Result : ".$result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick nicely.

```
$sentence = "zero one two three four five six seven eight";
$sentenceParts = explode (" ",$sentence);

$itemCount = count($sentenceParts);
$result = $sentenceParts[2]." ".$sentenceParts[3]." ";
for($i = 0; $i < $itemCount; $i++) {
    if($i != 2 && $i !=3) {
        $result .= $sentenceParts[$i]." ";
    }
}

echo $result;
```